# Floating Action Button going below CardView on pre Lollipop

Tags: android, android-cardview, floating-action-button

I am developing an android app. In it, there are two cards, and one FAB in between those two cards. The screen looks perfect in API 21, but below 21, the bottom half of the button goes below the second card.Two images have been attached : [PREVIEW BEFORE API 21](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K7xbQ.jpg) and [PREVIEW ON API 21](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hkUHB.jpg).Please help. Thanks!

xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <View
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:layout_height="5dip"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" />

<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_marginTop="05dp">

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/header"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="-4dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="-4dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="-4dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="-4dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="-4dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="-4dp"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:elevation="500dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="5dp">

    //First CARDVIEW ELEMENTS 

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/action_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:onClick="SampleClick"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:src="@mipmap/create_button"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/header"
        android:layout_marginBottom="-32dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/header">

        <View
            android:background="@color/colorAccent"
            android:layout_height="5dip"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:layout_width="match_parent" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/footer"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="-4dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="-4dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="-4dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="-4dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="-4dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="-4dp"
            android:elevation="500dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="5dp">

    //SECOND CARDVIEW ELEMENTS           

            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I provide you example please have a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can achieve that by adding `layout_anchor` tag to your FloatingActionButton  this mean draw my floating over this view , this will need you change your top layout to `CoordinatorLayout` as well

please have a look

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" // add this line
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/header"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="-4dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="-4dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="-4dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="-4dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="-4dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="-4dp"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:elevation="500dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="5dp">

    //First CARDVIEW ELEMENTS 

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
              android:layout_margin="16dp"
              android:src="@drawable/ic_done"
              app:layout_anchor="@id/header" // whatever you want
              app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end" />


<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/footer"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="-4dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="-4dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="-4dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="-4dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="-4dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="-4dp"
            android:elevation="500dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="5dp">

    //SECOND CARDVIEW ELEMENTS           

            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```